# inverse of $f(x,y) = (y+2,x+2)$

Tags: functions, inverse

I'm trying to find the inverse of a function with two variables,
such as  $f(x,y) = (y+2,x+2)$.  This is over real numbers.

It appears here that $x = y + 2$ and $y = x + 2$, so $f(1,2) = (4,3)$?  And if this assumption is correct then $f^{-1}(1,2)$ would yield an ordered pair of $(3,4)$?

What would be the inverse function?

Answer (score 1):

Let $(z,w):= f(x,y) = (y+2,x+2)$ and solve for $x$ and $y$ in terms of $z$ and $w$.

> $f^{-1}(z,w) = (x,y) = (w-2,z-2)$

Comment: So then y = z - 2 and x = w - 2.  Then substitute y for w and x for z to get f-1(y-2,x-2)?  I'm just trying to understand the steps I'd take.

Answer (score 0):

The inverse function is simply $f^{-1}(x,y)=(y-2,x-2)$, which you can verify with your first point.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  This makes sense now.  So the inverse function is taking the ordered pair from f(1,2) which is (4,3) and mapping a function to it so we get back (2,1)?

Comment: @CharlesOwen You should not switch anything. If $f(1,2)=(4,3)$, then $f^{-1}(4,3)=(1,2)$.